# Clipping image with SVG path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So, I've been developing an app, and the Idea is that all the avatars are going to be inside Hexagons.

I'm trying for two days already to insert the image inside the shape and tried clipping the image in the size, but the paths are completely crazy, I don't know anymore what I can do.

```
class HexagonClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 200;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 220;
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(376.87 * _xScaling, 339.93 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      339.93 * _yScaling,
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      217.52 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      708 * _yScaling,
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      708 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      708 * _yScaling,
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      616 * _yScaling,
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      536.22 * _xScaling,
      432 * _yScaling,
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      339.93 * _yScaling,
      376.87 * _xScaling,
      339.93 * _yScaling,
    );
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

(I converted an SVG with the format desired using https://itchylabs.com/tools/path-to-bezier/ )
When I clip the Image, it simply disappears, this is the code of my stack:

```
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipPath(
                      clipper: HexagonClip(),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 220,
                        width: 200,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/imgs/pessoa.png',
                        ),
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: use [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_drawing/latest/path_drawing/parseSvgPathData.html) to get `Path` and then scale it with `Path.transform` method, sample code here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/fc8c1bcc0a4fe67f04b05f3bb0c35e37

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me a lot :)